# keep non fungible token in blockchain log

Tags: ram, tokens, nonfungible

The dapp we are working on will have billions of NFT tokens. Our nft token is something that is added to blockchain only when user buys it. Before that it 'sits' in off-chain db.
For the sake of resource optimization we want to try out the following approach:

1. In EOS we can know the state in 2 ways: look at the state in RAM or search through the history in blockchain
2. In many cases when we need to store info in RAM to notarize it, we maybe able to save the ram if we don't need to keep that data persistent in the RAM. We might only need RAM to operate the contract or authorization to happen and then just free it
3. We can always see transaction details in blockchain and see what was the last time when certain NFT was transferred to a certain user - hence know the latest owner.

Question is:
Given the approach above, will our token still have 'non-fungible' nature?

Comment: How do you transfer the ramaining token from off chain db to you EOS blockchain ?